# onSuggestionStateChange in react-draft-wysiwyg not working

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I have written below Editor block and `onSuggestionStateChange` calling function which filter the text as per suggestion it was working as expected but now it is not working do any one have idea is there any changes in this parameter ?

```
      <Editor 
      mention={{
        separator: ' ',
        trigger: '@',
        environment:'',
        Category:"",
        suggestions: this.state.suggestionsState,
      }}
      enableurl={{separator: '', trigger: 'https://',}}
      enablenonsecureurl={{separator: '', trigger: 'http://',}}
      enablewwwurl={{separator: '', trigger: 'www.',}}
      tabIndex={3}
      ref={this.setEditor}
      onSuggestionStateChange={this.onSuggestionStateChange}
      editorRef={setEditorReference} onFocus={this.hidePlaceHolder.bind(this)} onBlur={this.showPlaceHolder.bind(this)} toolbarHidden editorState={this.state.editorState} toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
      wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName form-control contribute-text-area" editorClassName="editorClassName" placeholder="" onEditorStateChange={this.contributionTextChange}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any `onSuggestionStateChange` in `Editor` component. Please go through this [documentation](https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/docs?_k=jjqinp). You'll find `onEditorStateChange`, `onContentStateChange` or `onChange` props that can be used to trigger when editor state changes.

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I tried putting alert in this function but it get  call them on component load not on change

Comment: Can you help where should i bind {this.onSuggestionStateChange} function so as soon as user type trigger it start giving them suggestions